# How can we read, parse a autocad .dwg file and extract information from it programmatically?

Tags: .net, autocad, cad, autodesk, objectarx

I am trying to make a application which can import a .dwg file and analyze it and show the necessary information I need(e.g. a particular view area). I want to know how it can be done programmatically using .NET technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Teigha.NET, more info here: http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform

Answer (score 2):

Perhapse an old question but regarding to the question you can use an other good product as well. It is called [CadLib](https://woutware.com/) I have used it myself with ASP.NET webapplications. Also you can find a support forum where you can ask how you should select objects in the DWG file using a lower and upper coordinate.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your answer and we hope to see you making more valuable contributions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase a .dwg file reader from called [RealDWG](http://www.autodesk.com/realdwg) from AutoDesk.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what particular type of information you're wanting to obtain from the DWG file, you can also load the DWG file via the AutoCAD Core Console and extract the information you need into an external file.